Unable to click on modal close button with data-bs-target in Selenium WebDriver
I'm working on an automated test using Selenium WebDriver for a web page that contains a module with several photos and multiple associated parameters. Each photo has a "Detail" button that opens a modal (a pop-up window within the same page) with more information. This modal also includes a button to close it, allowing the user to continue viewing the other photos.
the code
package Selenium;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import io.qameta.allure.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.time.Duration;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)

public class MesadeControl {
private WebDriver driver;
By Email = By.id("Email");
By Password = By.id("Password");
private static String nombreAleatorio;

private String generateRandomName() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
}

public void logOn() {
    try {   
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://webpage.localhehe.com");
        driver.findElement(Email).sendKeys(nombreAleatorio + "fakepage.com.mx");
        driver.findElement(Password).sendKeys(nombreAleatorio + "123");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-user.btn-block")).click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        Allure.addAttachment("Error", "text/plain", e.getMessage(), "txt");
    }
}

public String verificacionExamples() {
    logOn();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Verificacion 1:1']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resultados")).click();
    driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("#pruebaId option[value='"+ driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pruebaId")).findElements(By.tagName("option")).stream()
                            .mapToInt(option -> Integer.parseInt(option.getAttribute("value"))).max().getAsInt()+ "']")).click();
    String pruebaNombre = driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("#pruebaId option[value='"+ driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pruebaId")).findElements(By.tagName("option")).stream()
                    .mapToInt(option -> Integer.parseInt(option.getAttribute("value"))).max().getAsInt()+ "']")).getText(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Cargar Prueba')]")).click();
    return pruebaNombre;
}

public void logOnAdmin() {
    try {   
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://webpage.localhehe.com");
        driver.findElement(Email).sendKeys("admin@thatsnottherealid.com.mx");
        driver.findElement(Password).sendKeys("passwordhehe");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-user.btn-block")).click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        Allure.addAttachment("Error", "text/plain", e.getMessage(), "txt");
    }
}


@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    //Chrome Drivers
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();


    if (nombreAleatorio == null) { 
        nombreAleatorio = generateRandomName();
    }
}

@Test
@Order(1)
@Epic("Modulo Calidad")
@Feature("Funcionalidad")
@Story("Resultados de Calidad")
@Severity(SeverityLevel.BLOCKER)
@DisplayName("Muestras de Calidad")
@Description("Esta prueba verifica la funcionalidad del apartado de Resultados y verifica los parámetros")
public void verificacionResultados() {
    logOnAdmin();

   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Calidad']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resultados")).click();
    WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("CalidadId"));
    Select select = new Select(selectElement);
    select.selectByVisibleText("2137e52a QA Pruebas jiji");
    WebElement botonCargarPrueba = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Cargar Prueba')]"));
    botonCargarPrueba.click();

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,900);");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    
    Map<String, String> umbralesEsperados = new HashMap<>();
    umbralesEsperados.put("blur", "0.5500");
    umbralesEsperados.put("lips", "0.0195");
    umbralesEsperados.put("dark", "0.2451");
    umbralesEsperados.put("even", "0");
    umbralesEsperados.put("eyes", "0.1176");
    umbralesEsperados.put("grin", "0~1");
    umbralesEsperados.put("pose", "0.8100");
    umbralesEsperados.put("rest", "0");
    umbralesEsperados.put("same", "0.0930");
    umbralesEsperados.put("size", "0.5500");
    umbralesEsperados.put("skin", "0.7700");
    umbralesEsperados.put("spot", "0.3070");
    umbralesEsperados.put("tall", "0.5500");
    umbralesEsperados.put("wash", "0.0203");
    umbralesEsperados.put("wide", "0.6503");
    umbralesEsperados.put("data", "0.0220");
    umbralesEsperados.put("face", "0.2503");
    umbralesEsperados.put("nose", "0.8000");
    
    String[] detallesIds = {
        "#modalDetalleCalidad-684275",
        "#modalDetalleCalidad-684276",
        "#modalDetalleCalidad-684277",
        "#modalDetalleCalidad-684278"
    };

   
    for (String detalleId : detallesIds) {
        try {
            WebElement botonDetalle = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-bs-target='" + detalleId + "']")));
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", botonDetalle);
            botonDetalle.click();

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h5/b[text()='Enrolamiento']")));//table for verfication

            Allure.addAttachment("Evidencia de detalle abierto para " + detalleId,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));

            WebElement tablaEnrolamiento = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5/b[text()='Enrolamiento']/ancestor::div/following-sibling::table[1]"));
            List<WebElement> filas = tablaEnrolamiento.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr"));
        
            // Map to control which criteria are found
            Map<String, Boolean> criteriosEncontrados = new HashMap<>();
            for (String criterio : umbralesEsperados.keySet()) {
                criteriosEncontrados.put(criterio, false);
            }

            //table to compare
            for (WebElement fila : filas) {
                String criterio = fila.findElement(By.xpath("td[1]")).getText().trim(); 
                String valorReferencia = fila.findElement(By.xpath("td[3]")).getText().trim(); 

                if (umbralesEsperados.containsKey(criterio)) {
                    String umbralEsperado = umbralesEsperados.get(criterio);
                    criteriosEncontrados.put(criterio, true); 

                    
                    if (!umbralEsperado.equals(valorReferencia)) {
                        Allure.addAttachment("Error: Criterio " + criterio + " no coincide para " + detalleId,
                                new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
                        System.out.println("Error en criterio: " + criterio + " - Esperado: " + umbralEsperado + ", Encontrado: " + valorReferencia);
                    }
                }
            }

         
            for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : criteriosEncontrados.entrySet()) {
                if (!entry.getValue()) {
                    Allure.addAttachment("Error: Criterio faltante " + entry.getKey() + " para " + detalleId,
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
                    System.out.println("Criterio faltante en la tabla: " + entry.getKey());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Allure.addAttachment("Error durante la validación", "text/plain", e.getMessage(), "txt");
        }
    }

    // Close modal
    try {
        WebElement botonCerrar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @class='btn-close' and @data-bs-dismiss='modal']"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(botonCerrar)).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Allure.addAttachment("Error al cerrar el modal", "text/plain", e.getMessage(), "txt");
    }
}@AfterEach
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

Something else I forgot to mention is that there are several closing tabs with the same button and the same class, ranging from windows with details to others from different modules.
The issue I'm facing is when I try to automate the click on the modal's close button. I'm using Selenium to interact with the button, but I keep getting an error when trying to execute the .click() function on it. What's strange is that clicking on other elements on the page works just fine. I've tried various ways to select the button, such as:
WebElement closeButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-bs-dismiss='modal']")));
closeButton.click();

I've also tried the following methods to identify and click the button:
By CSS Selector:
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-close")).click();

By XPath using multiple attributes:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @class='btn-close' and @data-bs-dismiss='modal']")).click();

By XPath using the aria-label attribute:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close']")).click();

Despite trying these different methods, I keep encountering an error stating that the button is not clickable. I am confident that the button mapping is correct, as I have verified its location in the DOM multiple times, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.
Environment Details:
Browsers: Tested on the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.
Selenium WebDriver: Updated to the latest version.
Relevant HTML Code for the Modal:
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalDetalleCalidadLabel">Details</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-success">
            <b>Enrollment</b>
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
        <!-- Table content -->
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

My code runs in eclipse without any apparent failure in the JUnit delivery console, but the error that it shows me in the report in allure is this one:
element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn btn-sm btn- 
success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
target="#modalDetalleCalidad-684276">...</button> is not clickable 
at point (690, 13). Other element would receive the click: <div 
class="modal fade show" id="modalDetalleCalidad-684275" 
tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalDetalleCalidadLabel" aria- 
modal="true" role="dialog" style="display: block;">...</div>

Question:
Has anyone faced a similar issue or has any idea why Selenium cannot click on the modal's close button? Could it be a compatibility problem with the drivers, or is there something else I should consider?
I appreciate any help or suggestions you might have.

Can you give more details for your question? More test codes, the dialog HTML source codes, and the error message. Maybe it is caused by the dialog being added to the dom after you click the "Detail" button. you can try to pause for 1 second before you click the close button. but this is not the best solution. I can give more details after you give more details of this issue.

Thank you very much. I updated the post with more information. Even though Eclipse doesn’t show any warnings when running the automated test, at no point can the pop-up window be seen closing.

Try to switch to the model and then click on close
driver.switchTo().activeElement();

or
driver.switchTo().frame('modelFrame');//replace with your model frame name


Dont´t works :(

The error log gives the exact root cause: The button you want to click is covered by another DIV element.
Please double check:

Is this button correctly located? From the error log, your codes will click the button:
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalDetalleCalidad-684276">...</button>


What's the modal dialog? it covered the button when you perform click action.
 <div class="modal fade show" id="modalDetalleCalidad-684275" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalDetalleCalidadLabel" aria-modal="true" role="dialog" style="display: block;">...</div>



You may add a breakpoint in the click action, debug your codes, and then check the browser to find the modal dialog covering the button.

That error occurs because the tab is still open when trying to continue opening the other tabs, specifically those with that ID. Something else I forgot to mention is that there are several closing tabs with the same button and the same class, ranging from windows with details to others from different modules.

If there are several buttons with the same class exist. You need to update your element locator to identify the correct button. Usually, you may locate the button with its parent/ancestor container to find the correct button. Or you may enumerate all the same class buttons and check the 'Clickable' of these buttons. click the 'Clickable' button.
